# Out of 3 identical sscanf calls, the middle one does not work

Tags: c++, scanf

I have no idea what is happening

In my C++ program I wanted to simply read some parameters from the command line.

1. variables are defined at beginning of main():

```
    uint32_t sampling_frequency;
    uint32_t samples_per_pixel;
    uint32_t total_samples;
    uint16_t amplification;
```

2. after some verification of argc, I'm reading them:

```
    sscanf(argv[3], "%" PRIu32, &sampling_frequency); 
    sscanf(argv[4], "%" PRIu32, &samples_per_pixel);
    sscanf(argv[5], "%" PRIu16, &amplification);
```

3. immediately after, printing the acquired values for debug purposes:

```
    printf("%s: %" PRIu32 "\n", argv[3], sampling_frequency);
    printf("%s: %" PRIu32 "\n", argv[4], samples_per_pixel);
    printf("%s: %" PRIu16 "\n", argv[5], amplification);
```

4. here comes the big surprise, when I run the program:

```
4.b:~/pro/spectr> ./spectr spectr_02.png out.wav 44100 10 2 -9 -8 -5 -4 -2 0 2 3 5
44100: 44100
10: 0
2: 2
```

As you can see, the 3 sscanf() are identical but for some unexplained reason it fails to work correctly for argv[4] only.
The problem is with sscanf() and not with printf() because the code later checks the numeric value and it indeed behaved as if was 0.
I have no idea why it behaved this way.

I'm compiling with g++ on Debian10 amd64.

Comment: even stranger, when I'm sscanfing in different order, i can make it work or not, but I'm still not understanding.

Comment: What is the return value of the second `sscanf` call?

Comment: I believe the read into "amplification" is affecting more than 2 bytes.

Comment: Side note: Since this is tagged C++, [std::stoul](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) may also be helpful. Eg: `uint32_t sampling_frequency = std::stoul(argv[3]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PRI*` macros are only suitable for *printing*, not scanning.

If you want to use these macros with `sscanf()`, you need to use the `SCN*` versions.

Like so:

```
sscanf(argv[3], "%" SCNu32, &sampling_frequency); 
sscanf(argv[4], "%" SCNu32, &samples_per_pixel);
sscanf(argv[5], "%" SCNu16, &amplification);
```

Comment: Ah, yes, of course!
How could I not remember this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong format specifier macros for scanf. The "PRI" macros are for the printf family. The "SCN" macros are for the scanf family.

Due to the fact that integer promotion applies to varargs, printf only needs size specifiers for types larger than int. scanf needs them for both types smaller than int and types larger than int.

Your platform has a 32-bit int and a 16-bit short. So the macros are probablly something like .

```
#define PRIu16 "u"
#define PRIu32 "u"
#define SCNu16 "hu"
#define SCNu32 "u"
```

So your incorrect use of the PRIu16 macro with scanf leads to you reading 4 bytes into a 2 byte variable. Since your system is little endian and is ok with unaligned acesses this reads the value correctly into the uint16_t but also overwrites the next two bytes of memory. What exactly is in that memory depends on how the conpiler happened to allocate variables on the stack,

In your case, it seems like `amplification` was allocated immediately below `samples_per_pixel`. So reading a four byte value into `amplification` overwrote the first two bytes of `samples_per_pixel`.